# How can I create a search bar and use the word (name) from each document from my API instead of their ID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onsubmit

I'm new to React and trying to create a search bar.

I have an api and a backend, which I created, it has brand names and logos (and id's). I am using Insomnia to see if I can access each document and I can access them all.

On the front end, I have an index page with brand cards and on this page I can click on an individual brand card and it takes me to a showpage with details on that brand. When this happens, the url gets added the id of each brand.

I also have a homepage and I am trying to create a search bar where I can search the name of the brand and it takes me to the showpage I mentioned above. However, when I do a search it takes me to a blank page, with the word I searched added to the url. I need to filter or find the name of the brand and connect it to it's id and get the search result to appear.

This is what I have so far. And it is not working. I am not sure what to add. Any tips and recommendations would be appreciated! Thank you.

```js
const history = useHistory()
const [userBrand, setUserBrand] = React.useState('')
const brands = React.useState('')

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  userBrand.toLowerCase()

  const searchedBrand = brands.find(brand => brand.name === userBrand.toLowerCase())
  const searchedBrandId = searchedBrand._id

  console.log(searchedBrandId)
  history.push(`/${searchedBrandId}`)
}
```

Comment: Why the drastically different calls to `useState`?  Shouldn't the second one be: `const [brands, setBrands] = React.useState('');` instead?  (Or probably set the initial state to an empty array instead of an empty string?)  What do you expect `brands` to be and why?

Comment: Thanks David! yes I can use ```const [brands, setBrands] = React.useState('')```
at the moment, when I console.log(brands) it doesn't bring anything on the console.

Comment: In that case where do you ever call `setBrands`?  The initial state of `brands` would be an empty string.  Why do you expect it to be anything else?  (And if you're calling `.find()` on it then you *probably* want to set it to an array, not a string.)

Comment: I haven't called setBrands anywhere yet. That's the thing, I've got code to remove but I'm not sure what to add to make it work. Have you got any suggestions re what I should put instead?

Comment: In that case it's not really clear what you're asking.  You *explicitly* don't have any elements in the `brands` array and you're trying to *find* elements in that array?  Why do you expect to be able to find an element in an empty array?  Please clarify the question you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
const [userBrand, setUserBrand] = useState({name: 'nike'})
const [brands, setBrands] = useState([{name: 'nike'}, {name: 'adidas'}]);
.....
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const searchBrand = brands.find(b => b.name === userBrand.name);
}
.....
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander! I've done the backend and api, and getting the documents from it. So I can't hard code the brands in an array like that. That's the point where I am having difficulty, I can't access the documents.

Comment: Hi, @EsinYil. Can u show the code where you get data from the backend and save it.

Comment: This is where I get my data from:

```React.useEffect(() => {
    const getBrandData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('/api/brands')
      console.log(response.data)
      setBrands(response.data)
      
    }
    getBrandData() 
  }, [])```

hope this was what you asked for?